# How to change the text between html tags

Tags: html, python-3.x

I have the example html code in the variable:

```
html_body = '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>......'
```

I need to modify the text between all the tags. for example

```
....<div class="css classes">text1</div>
<span id="some_id">
  <h1>Link: </h1>
  <a href="http://example.com/example">
    Link1
  </a>
  Click to open
</span>....
```

Using some function...

```
new_html_body = modifyHTMLCode(html_body)
```

and it should return this:

```
....<div class="css classes">text1_modified</div>
<span id="some_id">
  <h1>Link: _modified</h1>
  <a href="http://example.com/example">
    Link1_modified
  </a>
  Click to open_modified
</span>....
```

What is the easiest way to do this? I need to save the html structure, only modify the text

Comment: Have you looked at the standard library module `html.parser` yet?

Comment: You can make use of beautiful soup to modify the html file in python. Check it at https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/